complex optimization in the plane
I am trying to get the following condition:
$\forall\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C}\,\,\exists\,u,v\in\mathbb{T}\colon\quad|\alpha^2uv-(\beta u-\gamma v)^2|-|\alpha^2+4\beta\gamma|=|\beta u+\gamma v|^2$.
If the numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are all real or if $\alpha$ is real and $\gamma=\overline{\beta}$ then the above equation is satisfied. But the general case is not clear for me. This looks as a complex optimization problem and this is not the field I feel familiar with. Does anybody have an idea where to look for a solution? Or maybe one can provide a counterexample?

You have a typo which makes the problem impossible to understand.  Is the first equals sign supposed to be a minus sign?

The condition holds:
By dividing both sides by $|u|^2$ we see that your condition is equivalent to:
$$\forall\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C}\,\,\exists\,w\in\mathbb{T}\colon\quad|\alpha^2w-(\beta -\gamma w)^2|-|\alpha^2+4\beta\gamma|=|\beta +\gamma w|^2.$$
Writing $D=\alpha^2+4\beta\gamma$, we can rewrite this further as:
$$\forall\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C}\,\,\exists\,w\in\mathbb{T}\colon\quad|(\beta +\gamma w)^2-Dw|=|(\beta +\gamma w)^2|+|D|.$$
This is trivial if $D=0$. It is also clear if $|\beta|=|\gamma|$, because we may then take $w=-\beta/\gamma$ (or arbitrary $w$ in case $|\beta|=|\gamma|=0$).
So assume that $D\ne0$ and that $|\beta|\ne|\gamma|$. By using polar coordinates, you can check that if, for some $w\in\mathbb{T}$, $$w=-\frac{\beta +\gamma w}{\overline{\beta +\gamma w}}\sqrt{\frac{\overline{D}}{D}},$$ then $w$ solves the equation (just consider the norm and the argument of $-Dw$). By writing $\overline{w}=w^{-1}$, you therefore finally see that $$w=-\frac{\overline{\gamma}+d\beta}{\overline{\beta}+d\gamma}$$ is a solution, where $d=\sqrt{\overline{D}/D}$.

sorry for a two month delay...

No problem, better late than never!
